# I don't see the mistake in my SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, variables

Can anyone of you assist me? What's wrong with this syntax:

```
UPDATE subscriptions 
SET type_abonnement = 'premium', 
    betalingsmethode = 'EInvoice', 
    einvoice_email = 'email@email.com', 
    bank_naam = '', 
    tenaamstelling = '', rekeningnummer = '', 
    auto_afschrijving = '', 
    voorwaarden_akkoord = 'Akkoord met de voorwaarden', 
    gemachtigd_toezegging = 'Ik ben gemachtigd', 
WHERE 
    keycolumn = '5141d398ceeb7'
```

Error message:

> *You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE keycolumn = '5141d398ceeb7'' at line 10*

This is the echo of the SQL with the error message. The code I used:

```
$sql="UPDATE subscriptions SET type_abonnement = '".$typeabonnement."',
        betalingsmethode = '".$betalingsmethode."',
        einvoice_email = '".$emailfactuur."',
        bank_naam = '".$bank."',
        tenaamstelling = '".$tenaamstelling."',
        rekeningnummer = '".$rekeningnummer."',
        auto_afschrijving = '".$afschrijving."',
        voorwaarden_akkoord = '".$voorwaarden."',
        gemachtigd_toezegging = '".$gemachtigd."',
        WHERE keycolumn = '".$uniqueid."'    ";

echo $sql;

mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

mysql_close();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: remove the comma before the WHERE

Comment: I'm getting tired of all these mysql_* and SQL Injection crap floating around... [Read this.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15410966/1667004)

Comment: Please tell me you know about SQL injection....

Comment: Thanks pedromarce, that was it! @TheRest, thought it's not fool-proof: all the variables have been real_escaped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a comma `,` just before the where clause, which is the likely cause of this. Here:

```
... 'Ik ben gemachtigd', WHERE ...
```

*Remove the comma and it should work*

Comment: How could I've missed this?! thanks a lot!

Comment: You are less likely to make this mistake if you put your commas at the front of each line instead of the end.

Answer (score 3):

```
...gemachtigd_toezegging = 'Ik ben gemachtigd', WHERE keycolumn...
```

you have a comma before the WHERE = wrong

Comment: How could I've missed this?! thanks a lot gbn!